# How do I get my Batch file to echo ASCII characters properly?

Tags: windows, batch-file, character-encoding, ascii

Whenever I put in some special characters in my batch file, it ends up like this:

[image]

It's right, but there's sort of like a "T" behind the character.
Do you know anything that could help?

Comment: those characters are coming from whatever your batch file is executing...   You should paste the contents of the batch file.

Comment: That's a line drawing character - therefore you are using OEM fonts. Change to a proper font. Â is the character being shown.

Answer (score 0):

You can store the ASCII in a text file and load it into your batch file.

Example:

You store your ASCII into the text file `omg.txt` and then you need to use `type omg.txt`.

The only thing you can't do with `type` is to insert variable into the ASCII stored into the `omg.txt` file...

Comment: Nevermind, I found a perfect way to do it. (In notepad++ ofcourse)You just have to go to the Encoding tab located at the top bar and click Encoding. From there you click Encode in ANSI. Finished :)

Answer (score 0):

The display `Font` and `code page` affects the characters - and the code page that your `text editor` uses affects the characters when seen in a `cmd window` too.

`Foreign characters` and `Unicode characters` can be difficult to handle, or use special methods.

Answer (score 0):

To use ASCII characters, find the ASCII code of the character that you want to use. To do so, go to http://www.theasciicode.com.ar/ and then find your character. Next, go to http://www.alanwood.net/demos/ansi.html and in the second column find you ASCII code. Now copy the character in the first column. Now change the encoding of the program to ANSI and paste the character you copied into it. Sorry if this answer is sloppy, it's my first time answering.